# Ubuntu 12.10 / media playing problem

Tags: 12.10, media

I recently upgraded my OS and I have now Ubuntu 12.10 ( the Gnome 3 version ).
Since I installed this OS, I have a problem in playing media files or video/audio in general. At random times, ( usually every 2~10 min ) the media playing freezes for a moment and you can hear/see a hiccup in the audio/video.
This happens in every media, whether it's a video/audio file from HDD, stream from internet, youtube video, anything.

I have a sample file of vlc playing an audio stream.
http://www.sendspace.com/file/42ybmc

Does anyone know what this problem may be? I never had it with Ubuntu 10.04 or with Win7 on the same PC. ( there was not any hardware changed )

Comment: Is there anything on syslog? Any app crash?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it was a sound settings bug.
I changed the main device for sound output, from default "Analog Stereo" to "Analog Surroung 5.1 Output" 
( my sound card in embedded in the motherboard, but it has outputs for 5.1 sound )
Now it seems to work fine.